# Random io.EOF error when Read from net.Conn

Tags: go, network-programming

I have a simple Go program to read events from a server's daemon (text like HTTP headers):

```golang
package link

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "net"
    "os"
    "time"
)

type Link struct {
    conn   *net.TCPConn
    // reader *bufio.Reader
    // writer *bufio.Writer
    lines  chan string
}

func Connect(address string) (*Link, error) {

    raddr, err := net.ResolveTCPAddr("tcp", address)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    conn, err := net.DialTCP("tcp", nil, raddr)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    err = conn.SetKeepAlive(true)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    err = conn.SetKeepAlivePeriod(time.Second * 30)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    link := &Link{
        conn:   conn,
        // reader: bufio.NewReader(conn),
        // writer: bufio.NewWriter(conn),
        lines:  make(chan string),
    }

    go link.printLines()

    go link.readLines()

    return link, nil
}

func (link *Link) Login(username, password string) error {

    // Omit procedure

    _, err := link.writer.WriteString(msg)
    if err == nil {
        link.writer.Flush()
    }

    return err
}

func (link *Link) printLines() {

    for {
        line := <-link.lines

        fmt.Printf("printLines %s\n%s\n", time.Now(), line)
    }
}

func (link *Link) readLines() {

    const PacketSize = 10240

    for {
        buff := make([]byte, PacketSize)

        link.conn.SetReadDeadline(time.Now().Add(time.Minute))
        link.conn.SetReadBuffer(PacketSize)

        // Read from link
        len, err := link.conn.Read(buff)
        // Read from link

        fmt.Printf("readLines %d %#v\n", len, err)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("Error readLines %#v\n", err)

            if err != io.EOF {
                break
            }
        }

        link.lines <- string(buff[0:len])
    }

    os.Exit(1)
}
```

I ran this package with this code:

```golang
package main

import (
    "time"

    "./link"
)

func main() {

    link, err := link.Connect("HOST:PORT")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    link.Login("...", "...")

    // Wait for five minutes to read events
    time.Sleep(time.Minute * 5)
}
```

The question is, why this Go program ends before this deadline (5 minutes) with io.EOF error in `len, err := link.conn.Read(buff)` from net.Conn.

I try to change some parameters like Keepalive, KeepalivePeriod, ReadDeadline, and ReadBuffer.

**Currently, I have the same program but in Crystal-lang and works properly. I mean, this is not a server side problem.**

Comment: EOF typically means that the other end closed the connection, which is the default for HTTP 1.0 (connection is closed after each request/response). You need to either use a [HTTP persistent connection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection), or specify version 1.1 of the HTTP protocol.

Comment: Is not a HTTP request/response, it's a persistent connection. As I explain, the _same_ code it's running in other programming language.

Comment: Then you should first of all study the server-side logs. Even if it's not a server-side problem the logs could give hints about what's happening. And even if it works when using other programs, it doesn't mean it isn't a server-side problem. And no matter what, EOF on a socket is always that the other end closed the connection, so looking at the other end is a good idea anyway.

Comment: Is not a server side problem, there a running many others daemons.

Comment: Does the server send data every minute?  Show the program that works.

Comment: @JavierValencia Maybe you need to check if you get anything from server, except EOF error - https://golang.org/src/net/net.go?s=6487:6529#L170

Comment: @CeriseLimón the server is sending events each many miliseconds

Comment: @PiyushChugh when io.EOF `len` is 0

Comment: It’s difficult to determine why the server closes the connection from the posted information.  Tell us more about the server or share the code for the client that does work.

Comment: WTF! It's something related with MAC/OSX (where initialy probed), I try the same code in a linux box and works properly.

Comment: I would start by fixing all little problems and remove unnecessary parts from this. Don't allocate a new buffer for every single read call. Don't call `SetReadBuffer` or `SetKeepAlivePeriod`. Use the data read _before_ checking for EOF as documented, and don't continue on EOF. Don't use sleep for synchronization. Don't call `os.Exit` from an unsynchronized goroutine (and while not related, _do not use relative imports_). Also, you're referring to "packet size" and "lines", but there's no framing here, so it leads me to believe you are working with some incorrect assumptions from the start.